# Varnish Implementation on Magento Store

Tags: apache, magento, nginx, varnish

I want to implement varnish on my website.

Any one suggest what are the steps to follow to implement successfully with all hole punching.

```
Steps which i have already followed
1. Installation of varnish on the server.
2. Installation of https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine module
3. Hole Punching
```

Still i fing age 0 in header.

Please suggest entire installation procedure of Varnish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Manoj

So, your Magento website suffer slowdowns, and you thinks that it affects your conversions. You’re right.
You think that you’ll have to change your hardware to make it faster, but it seems to expensive.

A simple and effective way to speed up your site is to install a reverse proxy. Let’s speak about Varnish.
Varnish is a powerful reverse proxy cache server compatible with all HTTP servers, and is very easy to install.

So here i am providing you the link for the same from where you can easily find the help for the Varnish installation and you query will be easily resolved.

Link is  [1]: http://en.yrweb.fr/system/how-to/successful-varnish-implementation-with-your-magento-platform.html

Hope this solution will be useful to you !!!

Waiting for positive comments !!!!

Comment: i think this link for Apache can you provide me link for nginx+magento